# Hibernate HQL injection example

Tags: java, hibernate

Yesterday searching through some repositories on Github I found some interesting stuff: one Java project (I won't mention the name of the repository but I've already notified the owner of it) contained a bad handling of HQL queries which could lead to SQL/HQL injections. The code was the following: (note that `username` and `password` come from the user)

```
  Query query = session.createQuery("from Client where username = '" + username + "'");
  List clients = query.list();
  Client client = (Client) clients.get(0);
  if (!validPassword(client.getPassword(), password)) {
      return false;
  }
  //client is authenticated....
```

I think it is obvious that this query is injectable. I don't really know how this vulnerable query could be exploited because even if we inject the `username`, the 
`password` is still checked. The database used was `MySql` (if it helps).
 So my question is: how could this be exploited?

Comment: uhm... what is your question? A possible way of exploiting it?

Comment: yes, I updated the description.

Comment: String username = " name or 1=1";

Comment: yeap, this would return all clients, but still, the password of the first client is checked, and this cannot be exploited as it is.

Comment: if the driver allows it, you could append an update that changes the password to whatever you need. Is this generally allowed?

Comment: bobby tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though HQL is more restrictive than SQL for injections, it can still be exploited.

Some example injections are explained at https://blog.h3xstream.com/2014/02/hql-for-pentesters.html

A similar question to this one has been asked already before at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24265/hql-injection-example

The answer to this question explains how characters of a password (hash) could be scanned.  e.g. if for an Oracle database the value of `username` is:

```
admin' AND SUBSTR(password, 0, 1) = 'A
```

Then if

1. the first character of the password (hash) is not 'A' -> the clients List is empty and the `clients.get(0)` method call throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`
2. the first character of the password (hash) is 'A', but the provided password is false -> the user is not authenticated
3. the first character of the password (hash) is 'A' and the provided password is correct -> the user is authenticated

A hacker can repeat the query for each x and z in

```
SUBSTR(password, x, x + 1) = z
```

in the query above until the outcome is always case 2. where the user is not authenticated.  This way he can find out the password hash for the user `admin` and may be able to crack his password.

Other exploits are possible, I am not going to list all of them...

Comment: "all kind of nasty stuff" doesn't really answer the question in my opinion. The question is "in this particular case, what could be done?" Also, there's very little offensive stuff on bobby-tables.com.

Comment: You are right, but then I did not had the feeling the OP had done a lot of research and I would have to spend some time to set up an HQL environment to test what I would say.  It seems HQL is more restrictive than SQL for injections, yet injections are still possible.  I will update my answer to refer to some relevant links.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the nasty stuff on http://bobby-tables.com/ is in the cartoon.  You construct a SQL username of 4 parts: a random name, the string '); to close the query, all SQL queries you want to inject, the string -- to ignore the remainder of the original query, so your injected query is syntactically correct.

Comment: your new answer is great. I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes so...once you had start hibernate session, You can fetch data using query. Now you have written query for Client table.

For ex,

username = "ABC"

1) Your query from Client where username = 'ABC' will fetch data from Client whoes username is exact ABC. 
If it found multiple same Username, it also return all.

2) It is going to store in list. 0 or more record will store in list.

3) Then whatever records came, it fetch only first record using

Client client = (Client) clients.get(0);

4) it check with client object record password with your expected password that may be suppose to save in some variable via method calling.

5) if it won't match then it return with false boolean flag otherwise code will go ahead with authenticated client execution.

Hope you got your answer.

Comment: I think the question is more "given this code, how could I exploit it?" instead of "how do I fix this?"

Comment: Yes so...once you had start hibernate session, You can fetch data using query. Now you have written query for Client table.

Comment: Again, you seem to be answering a totally different question.

Comment: It *is* descriptive, you're right. It's just that you're answering a different question.